Discrete versus Continuous variables in online covering/packing problem
I am reading the survey of the design of online algorithms with primal-dual approach. There are two algorithms to solve online covering/packing problem. The first algorithm  is called a "discrete" version (the first pic), while the second algorithm is called a "continuous" version (the second pic).


I have two questions regarding these algorithms.

How do we implement the phrase "increase y continuously" in practice?
From the proof, I can see that the update rule of discrete algorithm is a lower bound for the update rule of continuous algorithm. I wonder if we have a continuous algorithm, how can we create a discrete version of the algorithm?

